# How can i generate the apk file

Tags: google-app-maker

There is a service on google that is new called app maker, you get this with every google gsuite package. here you can create web apps and also export them. but how can I export these files from the google app maker as an apk file and publish it to google play store, I have a developers account, I was referred to you by google admin support.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/getting-started/app-development-overview App Maker is a WYSIWYG ("what you see is what you get") interface for building web apps. You can customize your apps with scripts and CSS, and integrate with G Suite services through their APIs; Therefore, you can only build web apps not mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Maker is a tool to develop web application (both front-end and back-end) using AppsScript (JavaScript). You can directly view the result of your page on the web by publishing your version of the app or by simply previewing it. You cannot generate an APK out of it. The best you could do is export the whole application as compressed file.